# Creating nested object from divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a html page similar to the following. I would like to read fields and create a hierarchical javascript object (or json). How to do it? Thanks for any help.

```
<div class="t">
    <div>
        <div class="c">
            <input type="text"></input>
            <input type="text"></input>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="t">
    <div>
        <div class="t">
            <div>
                <div class="c">
                    <input type="text"></input>
                    <input type="text"></input>                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Resulting JSON should look like:

```
"result":{
   "id":"",
   "ver":"",
   "name":"",
   "desc":"",
   "tdata":[
       //nested elements from class 't' in the order they are in html
       //each input element under class 'c' for each class 't'. 
    ]
}
```

Comment: u'll have to code for doing this manually i think. There are no automated scripts that are so clever.

Comment: And what's blocking you ? Are you just asking us to write this code ?

Comment: I am working on it. I am not asking you to write code. I am asking for the idea. I am having trouble getting the first level children of class 't' and then the next level etc to iterate and compose the hierarchical structure. Thanks.

Comment: perhaps a little bit of structure of the desired output would help

Answer (score 1):

For going through `.t`

```
$('.t').each(function() {

});
```

For serializing `input` data in `.c`:

```
$('.c input').serialize();
```

If you want get all children and grandchildren you shoud:

```
var nestedElements = [];
$("#wrapper").find("*").each(function() {
    nestedElements.push(this);
});
```

Comment: This results in a flat structure right? every "t" is at the same level. If you notice my html, I have a "t" inside a "t". Thanks.

Comment: I see there is `.t` in `.t` but I dont understand question

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When I create the object, i should have a parent 't' and a child 't' in that case. Thanks.

Comment: you want to find all children and grandchildren, ... of all `.t`?

Comment: Yes. I should retain the order (nesting) in the object also.

Comment: I edited my answer, is this help?